# Magento log-ins and user views

Tags: magento

if I want to create a Magento e-commerce website whose products are only allowed to be seen by registered users (registered and approved by me), is there any Magento extension or way to do this? Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module and configure it as it is explained in readme file.

https://github.com/jreinke/magento-require-login